# Universities offering PHD in Economics or CS without requiring a masters degree

Tags: phd

I am an Information Management and Systems student just about to graduate in three years from college. Due to financial constrains I would like to pursue a PHD degree directly without having to go through Master degree which is extremely costly. I am determined to get a PHD either way. I have a 3.7 GPA and I got 730 in GMAT. I am looking for a good university (top 50) who offers Phd programs in economics, eCommerce, or something that is economics or computer science related without having a master degree. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The GMAT makes me think US, but it is usually for an MBA and not a PhD program. Most US PhD programs do not require you to have a Master's degree. Are you looking for a US PhD program without any coursework requirement or are you looking outside the US?

Comment: @StrongBad is exactly right. Most U.S. programs do not require a master's degree as a prerequisite to a PhD; you can earn your MA within the framework of the program.

Comment: @Jacob In most fields (such as computer science) that is true, but I'm not convinced this is the case for economics. In economics I know of at least 3 programs that admit you into the masters program, which often leads to the PhD program. These programs do not admit students straight into their PhD program. Often the masters program is unfunded. How much experience do you have with economics departments?

Answer (score 1):

**Generally you can get a place for a Ph.D. in the UK or US after your Bs.c.; however it is a time consuming process**.

For this I would suggest the following steps:

1. Ask one of your lecturers about this. They might give you recommendations based on their knowledge. For example if you want to do a Ph.D. in E-commerce try to ask this from a lecturer who teaches this.
2. Ask your personal student advisor or your last year supervisor. You need their recommendation letter more than anything to get a Ph.D. position besides your marks.
3. Look for lecturers in the top 50 universities yourself, and try to communicate with them through your university email.
4. Repeat till you get there! It might take up to a year to find a place; so meanwhile you could get a job so there will be no gap year in your CV.